# doxygen shows only one documentation in fortran

Tags: doxygen

I have a sample fortran code I would like to show here:

```
SUBROUTINE CALHEAT(ISTL_)  

  ! DESCRIPTION:
  !! @ details
  !> Subroutine CALHEAT takes the information from the atmospheric boundary
  !>   file and the wind forcing file and calculates the net heat flux across
  !>   the water surface boundary. 
  !
  !   The heat flux terms are derived from a paper by Rosati
  !   and Miyakoda (1988) entitled "A General Circulation Model for Upper Ocean
  !   Simulation".  The heat flux is prescribed by term for the following
  !   influxes and outfluxes:
  !
  !     - Short Wave Incoming Radiation (+)
  !     - Net Long Wave Radiation (+/-)
  !     - Sensible Heat Flux (convection -)
  !     - Latent Heat Flux (evaporation +/-)
  !
  !   Two formulations of the Latent Heat Flux are provided.  The first is from
  !   the Rosati and Miyakoda paper, the second is an alternate formulation by
  !   Brady, Graves, and Geyer (1969).  The second formulation was taken from
  !   "Hydrodynamics and Transport for Water Quality Modeling" (Martin and
  !   McCutcheon, 1999).  The Rosati and Miyakoda formulation will have zero
  !   evaporative cooling or heating if wind speed goes to zero.  The Brady,
  !   Graves, and Geyer formulation provides for a minimum evaporative cooling
  !   under zero wind speed.
  !
  ! MODIFICATION HISTORY:
  !! @author
  !>   Date       Author             Comments
  !
  !
  !! @ param[in]
  !> VARIABLE LIST:
  !>
  !>   CLOUDT  = Cloud cover (0 to 10)<BR>
  !>   HCON    = Sensible heat flux (W/m2)<BR>
  !>   HLAT    = Latent heat flux (W/m2)<BR>
  !>   HLWBR   = Net longwave radiation (atmospheric long wave plus back
  !>             radiation, W/m2)<BR>
  !>   SOLSWRT = Short wave incoming radiation (W/m2)<BR>
  !>   SVPW    = Saturation vapor pressure in mb based upon the water surface
  !>             temperature<BR>
  !>   TATMT   = Temperature of air above water surface (deg C)<BR>
  !>   TEM     = Water temperature in cell (deg C)<BR>
  !>   VPA     = Vapor pressure of air at near surface air temperature (mb)<BR>
  !>   WINDST  = Wind speed at 10 meters over cell surface (m/s)<BR>
  !--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to display author, details, and parameters using deoxygen. However, doxygen only outputs the parameters. Can anyone point out what I did wrong here ?

The sample output is given below:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Doxygen** use a special command. The complete list can be found [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/index.html)

For example

```
\author { list of authors }
\param [(dir)] <parameter-name> { parameter description }
```

For your code, try this:

```
\author Author name
\param [in] CLOUDT Cloud cover (0 to 10)
\param [in] HCON Sensible heat flux (W/m2)
\param [in] HLAT Latent heat flux (W/m2)
\param [in] HLWBR Net longwave radiation (atmospheric long wave plus back radiation, W/m2)
\param [in] SOLSWRT Short wave incoming radiation (W/m2)
\param [in] SVPW Saturation vapor pressure in mb based upon the water surface temperature
\param [in] TATMT Temperature of air above water surface (deg C)
\param [in] TEM Water temperature in cell (deg C)
\param [in] VPA Vapor pressure of air at near surface air temperature (mb)
\param [in] WINDST Wind speed at 10 meters over cell surface (m/s)
```

Comment: Note for Fortran routine arguments it is also possible to add the documentation after the variable e.g. INTEGER, intent(in) :: CLOUDT !< Cloud cover  ;in this case the intent and the name of the variable are automatically detected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your doxygen specific information before the SUBROUTINE command! See [the doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#fortranblocks) for more information.